# Lotus Notes - Creating a view to display all "marked as read" email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

seeking for advise to create a specific view in lotus notes.

aim is to have a similar view to 'all documents' - ie showing ALL the emails, also the ones already filed in subfolders BUT with applying a filter so it only shows those documents that were already marked as read.

thanks!

Comment: What's your underlying goal here?  Why do you want to be able to see all the 'marked as read' email?  Perhaps we can suggest something else.

Comment: My similar problem is, I created a view by year to auto-archive mails, but I don't want to archive unread mails (This is the reason I found this question). May be someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a view that only show unread documents.

Instead you can use the All Documents view (or any other view or folder) and the option to filter a view by unread only. Use the menu View - Show - Unread Only to use this filter.

Comment: Looks to me like the question is about the opposite: showing only the read messages.  There's no way to do that.

Comment: Ah, it sure is. Agree - that's not possible

Comment: Not without writing code to populate a special folder, anyhow.  And that's not something I would actually recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by doing the following.

1) Create a new folder in the mail file ( Unread ). 
2) Go to Inbox and then View Menu ->Show -> Unread only
3) Move all the Unread mails to the ( Unread ) folder
and then again go to View Menu->Show -> uncheck Unready only,
 ( so it will show all the remaining read mails )

after you archive then again move all the mails from the New Folder ( Unread) to the Inbox folder
Kamlash